# How do I give the complete faces a different Material?

Tags: materials, faces

When I give the faces in the inside a differerent material than the rest, the new color does not fill out the whole face as I would like (Possibly because of the subsurf Modifier?). How can I make the whole faces be blue?
[image]

Comment: It might be helpful to show the entire screen for blender to see your current modifiers and any other creases you have.  The face mode.  Your materials panel.

Comment: I see many face marks.  Perhaps too many.  Blender has an edge crease tool for use with the Subdivision modifier.  Another option is to make face of tiny width in x or y, or extra edge loops, which some people feel is inferior.  So do you have extra edge loops creating narrow faces?

Comment: Yes, most likely that is the result of Subsurf modifier. If you want to make material to end on the border of the inner part then you will have to find a way of preventing Subsurf from smoothing mesh too much there. It can be either supporting (proximity) edge loops or creasing existing loops like in the answers below. Another (more complex) way would be unwrapping mesh and painting on it a mask of where you want which material to be (black-n-white image). Note that mesh on the screenshot very likely has doubles, select all and press W > Remove Doubles

Comment: Consider creating a new model from zero.  The new model may have zero problems, because you may be more skilled on the second attempt.  You may have mistakes in the old model, and you many not need to know what they are.

Answer (score 2):

Create additional edge loops and it will stick to the edge

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have a bevel between the rim and the interior of your object with one segment. You have given that segment the material of the rim. Because of the [rules of Catmull-Clark subdivision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catmull%E2%80%93Clark_subdivision_surface), the bevel's face loop will be subdivided, each edge weighted towards pre-existing adjacent edges. Each subdivision receives the material of the original face loop. But the adjacent edges are further away down the length of the interior,so the material is drawn down into it.

If, instead, you have two segments in the bevel, and assign the inner one the internal material, and the outer one the rim material, the subdivisions will stretch the right way.

[image]

The top row has a bevel with one segment, the bottom row with two.

Answer (score 1):

Consider creating a second model made with creases.

Consider applying the Subsurf modifier and setting materials for the faces that suit your needs.

[image]

In the image above the right faint line is a crease.

[image]

The menu location of crease in the image above.

Famous video websites can well demonstrate edge crease use.