# How to bevel in proportion?

Tags: modeling, mesh, bevel

[image]

I have been doing this again and again and searched but cant fix it.
I think the bevel is not on the center of the edge

How to make better bevel?

Comment: I can't see the image because of personal reasons. I can try and understand your problem though. Firstly, have you applied your objects scale? Secondly, are all your normals correct? Thirdly, check for doubles and split edges? They can sometimes mess with the bevel modifier. Good luck with your project and I hope I helped

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82515/first-time-using-bevel-tool-doesnt-bevel-evenly-what-am-i-doing-wrong

Comment: If you're using sub-d, [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121051/how-do-i-give-the-complete-faces-a-different-material/121061#121061) may also be related. Under Catmull-Clark, edges are drawn towards neighbours further away.

Answer (score 0):

there's a short cut on edit mode: 
1 . select the edges you want to bevel. [works with faces too]

2 . press [ctrl]+[b].

3 . dragg the mouse to set the angle of the bevel.

4 . scroll the mouse weel to segment(loop) the arc.