# Having troubles adding material to a subdivided face

Tags: materials

I am a beginner in 3D modeling so I thought I'd give my AC remote a try as a first model, so far so good but I got stuck when adding a material, when not using a subdivider it all sits good:

https://gyazo.com/dce43d0964e769bdc6fba36c61efba3b

but when I enable the subdivider it only applies it to a small portion of it:

https://gyazo.com/eb1f29c34168bbfa41bb491e4c365787

Is UV unwrapping the solution? I'm fairly new to this, have no idea how to approach this since I have many edge loops all over it to sharpen the subdivider, which leads me to another question, how do you deal with a mesh after adding edge loops after it? I have many vertices sitting on top of each other, which makes it nearly impossible to select the right connected ones..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe [these answers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/121051/35559) are relevant

Answer (score 0):

Unwrap doesn't affect the material. Apply the modifier then go to edit mode, select the faces what you want to assign with the second material and select the second material, then click on assign.[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I did (as can be seen in the first gyazo link), but when I turn on the subdivider modifier it goes small for some reason.

Comment: Apply the modifier first, then assign the material.